# How many collector cards are required to beat each level of Rage Frenzy?

Tags: rage

Assuming that every collector card is collected during the game, when is the earliest point in the game where you can have a better-than-even chance of beating your opponent in each round of Rage Frenzy?

[All of the Collector Cards, in the order that they appear in Rage](http://rage.wikia.com/wiki/Cards).

Comment: I'm interested in answering this question because when I initially played the Rage Frenzy card game I usually lost, and then I did not come back to it until I had 20+ cards. By that point I was able to beat all 3 of Hendrik's rounds. It would be interesting to know how early in the game one can successfully start to beat Hendrik's rounds and make money out of Rage Frenzy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is not *how* many cards but rather *which* cards. You can pretty much flatten both opponets with an 11 card deck, however some of the cards are available really late in the game, I used the deck suggested [here](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/rage/128450-rage-trophy-guide-roadmap-2.html#post2196760):

> 1. Giant Mutant
> 2. Large Mutant
> 3. Slime Mutant
> 4. Kraken
> 5. Drop Ship
> 6. Enforcer
> 7. Shield Guard
> 8. Shrouded Minigun
> 9. Gearhead Jet
> 10. Captain Marshall
> 11. Valder

Comment: These are probably the strongest cards in the game (I've got all of these except for #9, and I have not yet reached Subway Town). However I was wonder what initial set of cards had to be collected to beat each round of Rage Frenzy, i.e. do I need the first 5 available cards or the first 9 available cards to beat the first round of Rage Frenzy? This is important because this card game is an easy way to make money if you have the right cards to win, and gaining this income earlier in the game makes a larger difference than later in the game.

Comment: I found out that in the game, money is hardly an issue, I played it on hardcore and almost never found out I don't have enough money. Given that one of the most powerful weapons in the game, the blade boomerang, is so cheap and easy to come by makes money even a lesser issue. I spent money only on components which aren't found in the wild and hardly ever bought ammo.

Comment: Also, since the game isn't completely linear, the term "first 5 cards" isn't really applicable

Comment: The game is fairly linear, except for the optional side quests. Since many of the side quests contain collector cards, it makes sense to complete the side quests as soon as possible to collect the maximum number of cards as early as possible.

Comment: Yeah, but since you're looking for "minimum cards as early as possible", it means some side quests which don't have good cards should be set aside in favor of better cards on main missions or other side quest. What I mean is, the term "minimum cards" is a bit problematic, I'd phrase it maybe "what's the earliest part of the game where you can have enough strong cards to beat opponents"